# Display directories in WP page/post

Tags: php, wordpress

I lost all day trying to find solution to display media content in page, the problem is that i need to display folders and sub folders inside the page or post, so the client (when on the website) can be able to walk through them and read, or download files. 
I was wondering if there is some plugin for this problem, but unfortunate i didn't find the solution. SO if there is some plugin or some WP inside function that i miss, it would be very helpful for me (and someone else).
If not i suppose PHP will be only cure for this. 
Thanks for help.

Comment: check this out .. much similar to your requirement http://www.simpleintranet.org/simple-files/

Comment: @PrakashRao Thanks Prakash that's what I was looking for, but I was also looking for a free plugin. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you are looking for:

```
<?php $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir(); ?>
<a href="<?php echo $upload_dir['baseurl']; ?>"><?php echo $upload_dir['baseurl']; ?></a>
```

Comment: Thanks @ambrooo, looking for something like simple files so that admin (don't know programming, just user of CMS) have control over files and folders. But thanks for help.